# How to save a record in CloudKit JS v2

Tags: javascript, cloudkit, cloudkit-web-services

Using CloudKit v1 you could save a record like this:

```
function demoSaveRecord(recordName,recordChangeTag,zoneName,name,location,asset) {

  var container = CloudKit.getDefaultContainer();
  var privateDB = container.privateCloudDatabase;

  var record = {
    recordType: 'Items',
    fields: {
      name: { value: name }, ...
    }
  };

  return privateDB.saveRecord(record,options)
    .then(function(response) {
      if (response.hasErrors) {
        // Handle the errors in your app.
        throw response.errors[0];

      } else {
        // It worked
        var createdRecord = response.records[0];
      }
    });
}
```

But in CloudKit JS v2 they removed the .saveRecord option.

So now I'm stuck because I can't figure out how to save a record in v2.
If anybody can help me, or can show me good documentation for v2, please help.

CloudKit JS API diffs v2
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/CloudKitJS_v2_APIDiffs/JavaScript/CloudKitJS.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you have to use `.newRecordsBatch().create(record).commit()` instead.

In my example it would look like this:

```
function demoSaveRecord(recordName,recordChangeTag,zoneName,name,location,asset) {

  var container = CloudKit.getDefaultContainer();
  var privateDB = container.privateCloudDatabase;

  var record = {
    recordType: 'Items',
    fields: {
      name: { value: name }, ...
    }
  };

  return privateDB.newRecordsBatch().create(record).commit()
    .then(function(response) {
      if (response.hasErrors) {
        // Handle the errors in your app.
        throw response.errors[0];

      } else {
        // It worked
        var createdRecord = response.records[0];
      }
    });
}
```

You can use the same method to create, update and delete records like this:

```
myDatabase.newRecordsBatch()
    .create(someRecord)
    .update(someOtherRecord)
    .delete(aThirdRecord)
    .commit()
```

Documentation can be found here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkitjs/cloudkit.recordsbatchbuilder